# Razor model does not return list of items to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new in MVC programming with razor and I need your advice on what is wrong with my code.

I have a Model

```
public class OrderDetails : OrderList
{
      public string CompanyId { get; set; }
      public List<OrderItems> OrdItems { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItems
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string StopAddressName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a controller that populate data.

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
      OrderDetails ordDtl = new OrderDetails();

      ordDtl.CompanyId = "1";
      ordDtl.OrdItems = new List<OrderItems>();
      for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
      {
          OrderItems tmp = new OrderItems();
          tmp.Id = i;
          tmp.StopAddressName = "Street " + i;
          ordDtl.OrdItems.Add(tmp);
      }

      return View("EditOrder", ordDtl);
}
```

When I send it to view it shows all data. Here is my view.

```
@model OrderDetails
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Orderlayouts", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <fieldset><legend>OrderDetail</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanyId)
        </div>

        <table>
          <tr>
             <td>id</td>
             <td>Address</td>
          </tr>
          @foreach (var itm in Model.OrdItems)
          {
          <tr>
             <td>@itm.Id</td>
             <td>@itm.StopAddressName</td>
          </tr>
          }
          </table> 

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

When I click the submit button I have in controller CompanyID, but OrdItems values become null. Can you point out what is going wrong with my code.
Here is my controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(OrderDetails Orderdt)
{
    return View("EditOrder", Orderdt);
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something major here, it looks like the only form field you have is CompanyID - so there is no OrderDetails object to retrieve.

Comment: You have to add your data to a hidden field since mvc can not parse the data into the correct object.

@Html.HiddenFor(model => itm.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => itm.StopAddressName)

This will serialize the data in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try doing Something like this.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.OrdItems.Count; i++)
{

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrdItems[i].Id)@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrdItems[i].Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrdItems[i].StopAddressName)@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrdItems[i].StopAddressName)

}
```

Comment: He can skip the HiddenFor annotation. Is not necessary in this case. Just for fields you don't want to show in fact.

Comment: Hmm really I thought I had trouble getting displayfor to save there values. I can go look at that though real quick.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works as expected. I changed foreach loop on for and yes I need HiddenFor because it returns 0 otherwise.

Comment: Awesome glad it worked for ya. If you could accept the answer would be great, or if it doesn't completely work yet can work with ya.

Answer (score 0):

Model binding is honestly the bane of my MVC work.

Here, however, you're going to see a `form` style post that only contains companyID - no other form fields for it to be using to bind are in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `OrderDetails` is an entity (tied to a database table via Entity Framework). For all entities with navigation properties of a list-type, you *must* use an `ICollection`. Additionally, all navigation properties, whether a single foreign key or a list, *must* be virtual. EF does not actually return your class, but rather a proxy of your class with the navigation properties overridden to return the proper objects. If it's not virtual, EF can't make the override and you get a null value instead. So your model should look like:

```
public class OrderDetails : OrderList
{
      public string CompanyId { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> OrdItems { get; set; }
}
```